# how to get the vertical dashed line while pointing or highlighting in a line chart in chart js or vue-chart js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts

the below image is from google , while highlighting a data point there is a circle pointerstyle and horizontal dashed line

[image]

this is a linechart drawn using vuechart js from my sample app, here while highlighting a data point, i got the pointer circle but no vertical dashed line!
[image]